# How to import an SVG logo in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I designed a logo on Adobe Illustrator. After exporting it as SVG
I tried to create an XML file using Android Studio to use but Android Studio says that this file can't be used.

Should I use specific options like using RGB colors only or what?

Thanks

Comment: Post your logo and if possible then the SVG

Comment: Download the svg version of this logo

Comment: https://icons8.com/icon/37684/fsociety-mask

Comment: I create the xml from this svg without any problem. Could you tell me which steps do you follow?

Comment: Right click , New drawable , And I select the svg resource ... Sometimes it work and many times no

Comment: When I create my own logo using illustrator it doesn't work ... And it doesn't work when I download an image from the web "png" and take it to illustartor the export it as svg

Comment: *Right Click -> New -> Vector Asset* and select he SVG

Comment: Is it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the  svg file by following this steps :

1. In the project Right click on the drawable directory
2. Go to New ⇒ Vector Asset
3. Click on the radio button saying “Local File (SVG, PSD)”
4. Click on the browse icon and navigate to your SVG or PSD file to select it
5. Finally click Next ⇒ Finish.

then you will see the  code generated from svg in the drawable directory